# suspect message "sshd-keygen-wrapper would like to receive keystrokes from any application"

Tags: security, ssh

I am receiving this message about "sshd-keygen-wrapper would like to receive keystrokes from any application", here is a screenshot:

[image]

I find it suspicious... this binary is located at `/usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper` and never had this message before. the closest to a solution that I found is that it is [harmless](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250352651)... does anybody know a bit more about it?

(disclaimer: I am using a MacOS, and this relates mainly with unix / linux software - so after some thoughts, I thought it was more apporiate to post it here than on another forum.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you run something *(apps/binaries/scripts etc.)* needing Accessibility Permissions while in an SSH session on that machine.

You can reproduce this in the following way:

1. Make sure to remove `sshd-keygen-wrapper` from the Accessibility list so it is allowed to ask again for permissions

   - [image: removing sshd-keygen-wrapper]
2. `ssh localhost` to SSH into your own machine
3. Run something requiring Accessibility Permissions

Here in my example I'm running the hotkey utility [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) to generate an <kbd>F11</kbd> event.

[image: running skhd under ssh]

So, if you're not connecting to your Mac through SSH, better check if you have SSH open without a password. Apple calls it Remote Login in System Preferences -> Sharing.

The only other way this could happen is if someone else logged in through SSH on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have just enabled SSH logins for you Mac - if not, I would find it suspicious too!

When you enable SSH logins, the system needs to generate a host key. The host key is needed for clients to be able to verify that they're logging on to the same computer each and every time they connect. This works the same way as on Linux and other Unix-type systems.

In order to generate a host key, the SSH software needs a lot of good, random numbers. An common input source in generating random numbers is sampling keyboard input (amongst other things). This is why it requests access to receive keystrokes.

You could give it access, generate the key and revoke the access immediately.

You could also generate the SSH host key via other means or on a different machine, and securely transfer it to this Mac. This way you won't have to grant access. The host key is stored in the `/etc/ssh/` folder.

Please note that you should not just copy over the host key already in use by another computer - this would defeat the purpose of the key!